# How to use Date property with Angular using my-date-picker

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I'm attempting to add a Date field to my MEAN app's input without using the `form` tag. To ensure that my solution is cross-platform I have opted to use the NPM module `my-date-picker` instead of the chrome-only `input type="date"` (I had to search a long time until I found out this was why there are no guides on this).

The idea is to set a value called `projectInstalldate`and then use it with my "add" function, which will pass it on through express and beyond. The problem I am having is with Date properties. no matter what I try i cannot seem to get access to them properly. hopefully my code will explain what i am trying to do:

projects.component.ts

```
//imports are here
import { IMyDpOptions } from 'mydatepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  templateUrl: '../views/projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ '../styles/projects.component.css' ]
})

export class ProjectsComp implements OnInit {
  //unrelated code
  //date: Date here?

public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    editableDateField: false,
    openSelectorOnInputClick: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd mmm yyyy'
};

constructor( 
  private projectsService: ProjectsService
) {
    //unrelated code
}

//Datepicker function
upDate(installDate: any) {
  this.date = installDate;
  this.newDate = this.date.toLocaleDateString();
}

add(
    install_date: any
): void {
    this.projectsService.create(
        install_date
    ).subscribe(project => {
        //unrelated code
    });
}
```

projects.component.html

```
<h4>Date Templated: </h4>
<my-date-picker [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
    [(ngModel)]="installDate"
    (inputFieldChanged)="upDate(installDate);"
    ></my-date-picker>
{{ newDate }}
<input class="hidden" #projectInstalldate />

<button class="projectButton" (click)="
    add(
        <!-- other field values here -->
        projectInstalldate.value
    );
">
    Create</button>
```

The idea is to get the value from the `my-date-picker` module and then turn into a `string` using `upDate()`. then display the value of `newDate` - at the moment yes it should just show up inside `{{ newDate }}` so i know it's working before i set the value of the input field to that.

the reason it's set up this way is because I have 30+ other fields here and i do not want to change it into a form, like the `my-date-picker` example suggests. I tried using the w3 schools Javacsript Date reference:

```
var date = new Date();
var newDate = date.toLocaleDateString();
```

but this just sets newDate to the current time. upon trying to use `installDate` from`my-date-picker`'s `[(ngModel)]` I get [object Object]. There should be a really simple to do this, but absolutely nothing I can find is helping. plenty of results for turning strings to Dates, but not the other way around. as you can see i'm trying to use `date.toLocaleDateString()` but every way i've tried to implement it has failed - I either get an error with the instance and then have to prefix with `this.date.etc.` and then get another error saying property `toLocaleDateString` does not exist on type `date`.

at my wits end here and would really appreciate anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so this problem has been stopping me from making any progress for about a week.

after looking at the documentation for moment.js i discovered a handy little pair of brackets...

```
upDate(installDate: Date) {
    this.date = new Date(installDate);
    this.newDate = this.date.toLocaleDateString();
}
```

and bam. now i know how to use `new Date()` properly. I haven't tried this with `my-date-picker` yet thought, i tested the solution using the chrome-only `input type="date"`.

EDIT: so now that i'm trying it with `my-date-picker`, I get a "invalid date" return from my `upDate` function. I assume this is because the `my-date-picker` is returning something other than a date object. anyone know if there is a way to get this out of an ngModel?